# Why this Code Work in "Visual Studio 2017" BUT Dose NOT work in "Visual Studio 6.0"

Tags: c++

This Code Work 100% in **Visual Studio 2017** But I Don't know why Does 
    not Work in **VS 6.0**

[The Result in Visual Studio 6.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rVKux.jpg)

[The Result in Visual Studio 2017](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qLtk6.jpg)

```
    #include<iostream>
    #include<assert.h>
    using namespace std;

    class stack
    {
        struct Node
        {
            int info;
            Node *link;
        };
        Node *Top;
        int count;
        int *list1, *list2;
        int i, x;
    public:
        stack()
        {
            Top = NULL;
            count = 0;
            list1 = new int[count];
            list2 = new int[count];
        }
        bool isEmpty() { return Top == NULL; }

        int TopStack()
        {
            assert(Top != NULL);
            return Top->info;
        }

        void Push(int num)
        {
            Node *newNode = new Node;
            newNode->info = num;
            newNode->link = Top;
            Top = newNode;
            count++;
        }
        void Pop()
        {
            Node *temp;
            if (!isEmpty())
            {
                temp = Top;
                Top = Top->link;
                delete temp;
                count--;
            }
            else
                cout << "the Stack is Empty." << endl;
        }
        void Input()
        {
            int num, Stop;
            cout << "Enter the stop Value : ";
            cin >> Stop;
            cout << "Enter the number : ";
            cin >> num;
            while (num != Stop)
            {
                Push(num);
                cin >> num;
            }
        }
        void print()
        {
            stack temp;
            cout << "\n The Number is : ";
            while (!isEmpty())
            {
                temp.Push(TopStack());
                Pop();
            }

            while (!temp.isEmpty())
            {
                cout << temp.TopStack() << " ";
                Push(temp.TopStack());
                temp.Pop();
            }
        }

        void Palindrom()
        {
            stack temp1;
            bool found = false;

            while (!isEmpty())
            {
                list1[i] = TopStack();
                temp1.Push(list1[i]);
                Pop();
                i++;
            }
            while (!temp1.isEmpty())
            {
                list2[x] = temp1.TopStack();
                Push(temp1.TopStack());
                temp1.Pop();
                x++;
            }
            cout << "\n\nThe list 1 : ";
            for (int t = 0; t < count; t++)
                cout << list1[t] << " ";
            cout << "\nThe list 2 : ";
            for (int r = 0; r < count; r++)
                cout << list2[r] << " ";

            for (int e = 0; e < count; e++)
            {
                if (list1[e] != list2[e])
                {
                    found = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            cout << endl << endl;
            if (found)
            {
                cout << "   -Not Palindrom" << endl;
            }
            else
                cout << "   -Palindrom " << endl;

        }
    };


    int main()
    {
        stack obj;
        obj.Input();
        obj.print();
        obj.Palindrom();
        return  0 ;
    }
```

If there is another way easier let me know.

Comment: Please include the header files, this `stack` class and `main`, as this is not a [mcve].  If you allow us to fill in the gaps, we are not running the same thing you're running.

Comment: Visual Studio 6.0 is a long obsolete piece of junk. If you are using it, you have a bigger problem than some code that isn't working.

Comment: Your program leaks memory.  The `stack` class you wrote does not properly clean up the resources.  Every time `Palindrom` and `print()` are called, `stack` leaks memory.  Use `std::stack` instead of trying to write your own.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You never initialize `i` or `x` before using them.  Thus you have undefined behavior.

Those variables shouldn't even be part of the `stack` class.  They should simply be local values used for holding temporary state.

You also have undefined behavior here:

```
count = 0;
list1 = new int[count];
list2 = new int[count];
```

You should not be allocating arrays with zero entries.  And furthermore, you should never be accessing those arrays outside their allocated memory.

There are many other things wrong with this code, but fixing these issues might help.